# Redirect to new url except for on page with existing expression engine redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, expressionengine

I have the following redirects in the .htaccess file:

---

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /content [NC]    
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.domain1.co.uk/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content$ [NC]    
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

The first redierect needs to be there for the expression engine to work properly. Visit to 
subdomain.domain1.co.uk/content matches the rule but I end up in the indefinite redirect loop. Can anybody help ?

Thanks,

EDIT: 2nd and 3rd rule may actually be incorrect. What I want it to do is to redirect anything from http://subdomain.domain1.co.uk/$1 to http://www.domain2.co.uk/$1 expect for http://subdomain.domain1.co.uk/content and http://subdomain.domain1.co.uk/content/*

Comment: Can you clarify what 2nd and 3rd rules are doing?

Comment: It might actually be incorrect. What I want it to do is to redirect anything from http://subdomain.domain1.co.uk/$1 to http://www.domain2.co.uk/$1 expect for http://subdomain.domain1.co.uk/content and http://subdomain.domain1.co.uk/content/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect everything except content/? to www.domain2.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain1\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/content/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: There is only one scenario which is not covered by this. www.subdomain.domain1.co.uk/index.php I would like to redirect to www.domain2.co.uk/index.php.  Any ideas?